# Group image sequence in a QFileSystemModel

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qtreeview, qtgui, qfilesystemmodel

I am using `QFileSystemModel` to represent file structure through the `QTreeView`. It works fine except that instead of displaying all image files in a directory, I would like to group all image files to a single expandable image sequence node, i.e. it will display one sequence node and if one clicks to expand it, all the image files will be displayed. Any suggestion how I could achieve this? Thanks.

Example:

```
-root_folder
  +image_sequence_%04d.jpg(222-1000)
  -folder_2
    +image_sequence2_%04d.jpg(1243-5050)
```

Comment: did you manage to do this? I am trying to do the same :)